How to solve this set of simultaneous equations to smoothly "weld" 2 functions together?
I have a function $\Phi(\rho)$ that is approximated well if I split it into 2 regimes, one for small values of $\rho$, which I will call $\Phi_S$ and one for large values of $\rho$, which I will call $\Phi_B$. These functions are: $$\Phi_S = \frac{\Phi_0}{8}\left( 8 + \rho^2 - \frac{3}{2} \Phi_0\rho^2 + \frac{\alpha}{2}\Phi_0^2 \rho^2\right),\space\space\space\space\space\space\dot{\Phi_S} = \frac{\Phi_0}{8} \rho\left( 2 - 3\Phi_0 + \alpha \Phi_0^2\right) $$ and $$\Phi_B = \frac{D}{\rho}K_1(\rho), \space\space\space\space\space \dot{\Phi_B} = -D\left( \frac{\rho K_0(\rho)+2K_1(\rho)}{\rho^2}\right)$$ where D,$\alpha$, $\Phi_0$ are scalars and $K_{\nu}$ are the modified Bessel functions of the second kind. I would like to "weld" these functions together such that for a given value of $\rho = R$, we have that $\Phi_S = \Phi_B$ and $\dot{\Phi_S} = \dot{\Phi_B}$. I would like to be able to plug in a value of $\alpha$, my free parameter and get out the values for $\Phi_0, D,$ and $R$ for which the function is smooth, if it exists. I don't care about the trivial case ie. $\Phi_0 = D = 0$. What would be the best way to go about solving this? And does a solution always exist?
